# How do I conditionally veto a delete attempt in Django Admin 1.5?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-methods) clearly state that `ModelAdmin.delete_model()` must delete the object and that it's not for veto purposes.  Trouble is, they don't give any hint how you *would* implement a veto *should* you need to.

Here's some background, because maybe there's an entirely better way to go about what I'm trying to accomplish.  I'm capturing iptables rules in a Django 1.5 app and wish to use the Admin pages to handle all the maintenance.  I have two models relevant to the issue at hand: Chain and Target.  Here's the crux of those models:

```py
class Chain(models.Model):
    """A netfilter chain."""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    built_in = models.BooleanField(
        default=False,
        help_text=u'This option should be selected if this chain is one of '
                  u'those provided by netfilter.  Leaving this option '
                  u'unselected indicates that the chain is user-defined.'
    )
    table = models.ForeignKey(Table, verbose_name='netfilter table')

class Target(models.Model):
    """A netfilter target."""
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=30, unique=True, primary_key=True,
        help_text=u'This may be either an iptables built-in target or a '
                  u'user-defined chain.  Built-in targets must be one of '
                  u'those supported by iptables.'
    )
    built_in = models.BooleanField(
        default=False, verbose_name='built-in',
        help_text=u'This option should be selected if this target is one of '
                  u'those provided by netfilter.  Leaving this option '
                  u'unselected indicates that the target is user-defined.',
    )
```

Thus the Chain table will have records for 'FORWARD', 'INPUT' and 'OUTPUT', all built-in and linked to the 'filter' table.  Of course the admin may enter other user-defined chains here too, but would set those with `built_in == False`.

It gets weird with the Targets though.  They can either reference a Chain (*hey, a ForeignKey would be great here!*) or a built-in Target (e.g., 'ACCEPT' or 'DROP') that I'd rather not expose as a Chain (*hey, a ForeignKey won't be so hot here!*).

Now the dilemma.  The Admin UI is a wee bit clunky for linking a Target to a user-defined Chain because it's not defined as a FK so I settle for a regular character input field and a `clean_name()` can handle the validation to ensure the Target's Chain exists.  I'm stuck on how to prevent deletion of Chains that are referenced by a Target.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this by overriding `has_delete_permission(request, obj)` in your `Chain` admin. You can check `obj` to see if any `Targets` are referencing it. See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_delete_permission).

This won't prevent deletion via the *Delete selected* action in the change list view, though. You can fix that by overriding the built-in `delete_selected` action with your own that refuses to do the delete if any of the items shouldn't be deleted. See the [Admin action docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/).

Comment: Thanks for that detailed answer.  Ultimately I wound up co-opting the Chain table to capture things that would've went in the Target table through the addition of an `is_target` field.  I was then able to employ `limit_choices_to=` on the ForeignKey's get the limiting appropriate for both the rule's associated chain and target.  This has the added benefit of ridding the rule admin of the clunkiness.